# How do I get all the bits that are on in one set of bits but not another

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Say I have 2 sets of bits. Pretend that they are two sets of permissions

- Desired Permission
- Actual Permissions

I want to know the desired permissions that are not set in actual permissions.

Is there a way to do this using only bitwise operators?

XOR will give me what is in one but not the other, but that doesn't tell me what desired permissions aren't set in actual permissions.

Comment: Do you mean `desired & ~actual`?

Comment: I think you are correct. Just tested with pen an paper. Thanks very much.